# GEE regression gives NaN values as result in a dataframe subset

Tags: r

Hi I run gee regression in a dataframe and take this result.

```
library(geepack)
    rightwmen<-coef(summary(geeglm(Ideo_Ordinal ~Machiavellianism+Psychopathy+Narcissism ,data = RightMen, id = Ideo_Ordinal,
                                   corstr = "independence"))) %>% 
      rownames_to_column() %>%
      mutate(lowerWald = Estimate-1.96*Std.err, # Lower Wald CI
             upperWald=Estimate+1.96*Std.err,   # Upper Wald CI
             df=1, 
             ExpBeta = exp(Estimate)) %>%       # Transformed estimate
      mutate(lWald=exp(lowerWald),              # Upper transformed
             uWald=exp(upperWald))              # Lower transformed
    rightwmen

 rowname   Estimate    Std.err         Wald    Pr(>|W|)   lowerWald  upperWald df     ExpBeta
1      (Intercept)  5.7656276 0.03107560 34423.423510 0.000000000  5.70471944  5.8265358  1 319.1392808
2 Machiavellianism  0.1319520 0.10168671     1.683851 0.194413479 -0.06735392  0.3312580  1   1.1410536
3      Psychopathy -0.4449102 0.15069337     8.716788 0.003152931 -0.74026922 -0.1495512  1   0.6408818
4       Narcissism  0.2291297 0.07617612     9.047429 0.002630645  0.07982453  0.3784349  1   1.2575051
        lWald       uWald
1 300.2812223 339.1816504
2   0.9348643   1.3927190
3   0.4769855   0.8610943
4   1.0830970   1.4599978
```

which seems normal to me.

When I run the same code in a subset of the initial dataframe (around 1300 observations) I take:

```
rowname      Estimate Std.err Wald Pr(>|W|) lowerWald upperWald df  ExpBeta lWald uWald
1      (Intercept)  6.000000e+00     NaN  NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN  1 403.4288   NaN   NaN
2 Machiavellianism -2.051668e-16     NaN  NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN  1   1.0000   NaN   NaN
3      Psychopathy  1.303711e-16     NaN  NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN  1   1.0000   NaN   NaN
4       Narcissism  4.350156e-17     NaN  NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN  1   1.0000   NaN   NaN
```

Note that I have omitted the NAs. What could be possible explanations?

```
#SAMPLE DATASET
A tibble: 588 x 4
   Ideo_Ordinal Machiavellianism Narcissism Psychopathy
          <int>            <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>
 1            5           0.0360   -0.0144       0.106 
 2            5          -0.425    -0.302       -0.259 
 3            5          -0.216     0.125        0.0879
 4            5          -0.776    -0.562       -0.488 
 5            5          -0.225     0.167        0.0309
 6            5          -0.167     0.107        0.0539
 7            5          -0.464    -0.00283     -0.150 
 8            5          -0.102     0.141       -0.0487
 9            5           0.237     0.676        0.399 
10            5           0.0220    0.00337      0.0293
# ... with 578 more rows
```

Comment: How do you generate the subset?

Comment: by choosing specific rows that match some criteria for example: CRM<-RightMen[RightMen$Ideo_Ordinal %in% as.factor(5),] #center men

Comment: Note that when I create another subset for example as.factor(5) it works so I suppose that it is a data issue . Maybe the values are too close for the certain subset?

Comment: Do the selected subsets look okay to you? Before running `geeglm`?

Comment: In my experience, this happens when a matrix involved in the numerical optimisation becomes singular (or close to singular). Does the function give you any warning message? Have you run it like this: geeglm(Ideo_Ordinal ~Machiavellianism+Psychopathy+Narcissism ,data = RightMen, id = Ideo_Ordinal, corstr = "independence")?

Comment: When I run it like this is it is ok. No I do not get warning messages.

Comment: For the full or the smaller data? And are the coefficients still wrong for the small dataset when you run it as suggested by @papgeo?

Comment: Full dataset is fine in any case. I do not get warning message for none of them.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't have your data this is a (wild) guess. I'll delete the answer if that does not solve your problem.

One problem I often encounter with `geeglm()` and `geepack` is that the clustering must be in order. So if you clusters could be identified as

`1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4`

then you have 4 clusters. However, if the clustering is

`1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4`

then you have 12 clusters. `geepack` identifies clusters as *changes* in the clustering variable (in your case `Ideo_Ordinal`). If you sample rows from your data then you might actually get too many clusters which can throw parts of the EE algorithm off because the data are no longer ordered.

This "feature" is super annoying IMO - so much so that I wrote a function to check for the ordering of the cluster specifically for this. Check out `MESS::ordered.clusters()` which returns `TRUE` if the clusters are ordered and `FALSE` otherwise.

Comment: You may have a point here. in the full dataset the result is false and in the subset is true because I only have a unique value(5)

Comment: Try adding an `arrange(Ideo_Ordinal)` to your pipeline before running the analysis. If you only have one cluster in the smaller dataset then that is likely the source of the problem

Comment: I tried to use it on the full dataset- arrange(RightMen$Ideo_Ordinal)- and I got :Error in UseMethod("arrange_") : 
  no applicable method for 'arrange_' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"

Comment: Should be something like `newdata <- RightMen %>% arrange(Ideo_Ordinal)` (and you need the `dplyr` package loaded first) and then use `newdata` in your call.

Comment: that was a great thing to fix indeed but does fix the issue. I still get NaN

Comment: I edited with sample. These 10 rows give the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176972/discussion-between-ekstroem-and-firmo23).